# 3D LiDAR synchronization with RGB Camera

Tags: cameras, sensor-fusion, lidar

There's a general procedure for estimating projection transformation between camera and 3d LiDAR but there's a secondary problem which is associating pixels with depths in a grid which isn't uniformly sampled.

What is the correct approach to doing this? Both the pre and post transformed depth points lack a grid structure. The pre-transformed points lack a grid structure because the sampling is time- instead of angle-based so you get variations in the angles. The post-transformed grid is obviously not going to be uniformly sampled either.

Comment: Define your terms first. Otherwise, nobody will understand your question.

Comment: Your problem is typically called ray casting. Back projecting the grid to the camera coordinate will work too.